# Solution to cache locally exported files and file deltas from Subversion

Tags: java, git, caching, svn, svnkit

I have a subversion repository and I need to implement a caching solution in Java where I need only to export a specific file revision and keep it locally for further use.

The problem that keeping all file revisions locally can't be done as the subversion repository keeps growing excessively , I only want to store deltas to reconstruct the specific revision I want from a base file and a delta.

I can't keep exporting files each time I need them for performance reason.

I use `SVNKit` to export files and store them locally for further use, and I store their revisions, remote paths, local path ... in an SQLite db to keep the association.

Obviously I can't create local Subversion repository like in `Git` or `Hg` ?

Is there any caching framework that can do that ?
Does having `Git` (by using `JGit`) to create a local repo for cache would solve the problem ?

Comment: Why can't you create local Subversion? You can and you can use something like 'svnsync' to keep the local repository in sync with the remote one. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: As I know with subversion, you can only create a central repository, annd which you can't directly commit code to it , so you will need a local copy to in order to commit, change .. edit